# Django Multitenant Single Login. after logged in it should be redirect to sub-domain

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, multi-tenant

I want to know how to access a Django multitenant user in a single login(my-domain.com/login). After logging in it should be redirected to a specific tenant subdomain(tenant1.my-domain.com).

Please give me a solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest developing a multi-tenant SAAS based app, where you can have multiple tenants running the same Django code but having different schemas in the Postgres, So your database for different domains will be completely separate from each other. I would suggest using django-tenant-schemas for this. Even if it takes you some time to set it up, I would suggest doing it. It will save a great deal of time for you in the future.

Customize your "User" Model and store the tenant ID with every user. You must have implemented the "get_tenant" function as it is necessary for django-tenant-schemas. In this function, check the tenantID on the user and return that tenant. After "TenantDetectionMiddleware", I have written another middleware. In this middleware, you can check for request.tenant and redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: my question is it is possible to single login for the multitenant user? i have already used django-tenant-schema

Comment: Yes, it is. I have set up in the exact same way.

Comment: Please tell the steps to sigle login for multitenant users. Please explain briefly how i do.

Comment: please share any reference